# Auto resize nstable row according to text

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, nstablecellview

I am very new to Mac development, I wish to create a chat application in OS X using swift language, I am using NStableView to display the messages, The height of the table row should be wrap according to the text size just like the following images [image]

[image]

[image]

As we can show the text will wrap according to window resizes.

my code is follows

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa
class ChatWindowVC : NSViewController,NSTableViewDataSource,NSTableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!
    private var arr = [String]()
    @IBOutlet var message: NSTextView!
    private var hgt:CGFloat = 20

    @IBAction func send(sender: NSButton) {
        if let textStorage = message.textStorage{
            if !textStorage.string.isEmpty{
                let str = textStorage.string
                arr.append(str)
                // textStorage.mutableString.setString("")


                tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        print("Send.....\(message.textStorage?.string)")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        arr.append("ONE")
        arr.append("TWO")
        arr.append("THREE")
    }

    func numberOfRowsInTableView(aTableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        let numberOfRows:Int = arr.count
        return numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> AnyObject?
    {
        return arr[row];
    }

    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        let result : ChatCell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("ChatCell", owner: self) as! ChatCell
        result.sent.stringValue = arr[row]

        return result
    }


    func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, heightOfRow row: Int) -> CGFloat {
        let str = arr[row]
        let c:Int = str.characters.count
        let cgfloat = CGFloat(c)
        print(cgfloat)
        return cgfloat
    }
}
```

Please guide me

**my problem is i could not set the row height according to the window resize**

The attached screen shot is an example of my target

It would be great if you can give an example or code snippet

Thanks a lot

Amith

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @rocky i have updated the question and sorry to mention the problem Thank you

Comment: Why my answer was deleted by @George Stocker. He even don't know swift language.

Comment: @Abin Joseph The answer is exactly what i want, Mr George has been deleted that is really not fair. I have post a question , got the exact answer then i shared my points to answered person, i think George have no rights to do this.

Comment: Where is the answer? Why did @George? delete it?